# jq : how to retrieve elements from lists of the same type?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json like this :

```
{
    "datasets": [
        {
            "features": [
                {
                    "name": "aaa",
                    "stringStats": {
                        [...]
                        },
                    "type": "STRING",
                },
                {
                    "name": "bbb",
                    "numStats": {
                        [...]
                        },
                    "type": "FLOAT",
                },
                {
                    "name": "ccc",
                    "stringStats": {
                        [...]
                },
                    "type": "STRING",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to retrieve all elements in [...] from all "stringStats" lists.

I succeeded with a jq query to retrieve all elements but I don't know how to filter and iterate from a specific kind of list.

Comment: Jq is a powerful tool but the documentation lacks examples. Consider using nodejs. I left Jq for the lack of a decent documentation.

Comment: @Azevedo thanks for you suggestion

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  In particular, it would be helpful if your sample was valid JSON, and if you could show the expected output.  (The shown sample is invalid as JSON in a way that is material to providing a solution.)

Comment: @Azevedo - Please note that apart from all the examples on the jq website (in the tutorial, the manual, the FAQ (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) and the Cookbook (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook) in particular), there are many examples on rosettacode.org (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Jq) and of course here on SO. Thank you, google, duckduckgo, and bing!

Answer (score 1):

If you need as array format use the below,

```
[.datasets[].features[].stringStats // empty ]
```

If you need as objects use the below,

```
.datasets[].features[].stringStats // empty
```

https://jqplay.org/s/-sZ7tvU4Yb

Comment: {name: .datasets[].features[].stringStats.name // empty, age: .datasets[].features[].stringStats.age // empty}

could this query run ? @Jagadesh

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using [`recursive descent ..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..), [`optional object identifier .?`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?) and [`values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars)

```
.. | .stringStats? | values
```

Answer (score 1):

You can us map to iterate over all values of array , and do what you want .

Data for my example

```
[
  {        "v": "1",        "t": "i"      },
  {        "v": "a",        "t": "s"      },
  {        "v": "1.1",      "t": "f"      },
  {        "v": "b",        "t": "s"      },
  {        "v": "2",        "t": "i"      }
]
```

example where i extract only when `t = "i"`

```
e444$ cat e.json | jq 'map(.| if .t == "i" then . else empty end )'
[
  {
    "v": "1",
    "t": "i"
  },
  {
    "v": "2",
    "t": "i"
  }
]
```

example where i extract only when `t = "s"`

```
e444$ cat e.json | jq 'map(.| if .t == "s" then . else empty end )'
[
  {
    "v": "a",
    "t": "s"
  },
  {
    "v": "b",
    "t": "s"
  }
]
```